# How do I find all zip codes in my table whose average sales are higher than the table average?

Tags: mysql

I am unable to figure out how to show which groups have higher sales than the table average. Where am I going wrong in the code?

This is to understand which zip codes produce the most sales above the average sales revenue of the table. I am using this as a procedure as I build out my database and event data visualization platform

```
SELECT PostalCode, AVG(SellingPrice), COUNT(PostalCode)
FROM sales_2018
WHERE AVG(SellingPrice) > 30000
GROUP BY PostalCode
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

I expected columns showing PostalCode, AVG(SellingPrice), COUNT(PostalCode), only with postal codes whose average selling price is higher than the average selling price of all rows.

This is returning

> Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Comment: Instead of placing the condition in a Where clause, use a Having clause, since the condition involves an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to check the average:

```
SELECT PostalCode, SellingPrice
FROM sales_2018
WHERE SellingPrice > (SELECT AVG(SellingPrice) FROM sales_2018);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `having` clause instead of `where`

```
SELECT PostalCode, AVG(SellingPrice), COUNT(PostalCode)
FROM sales_2018
GROUP BY PostalCode
HAVING AVG(SellingPrice) > 30000
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

or you can use `subquery`.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT PostalCode, AVG(SellingPrice) as SellingPrice, COUNT(PostalCode)
    FROM sales_2018 
    GROUP BY PostalCode) t1
WHERE t1.SellingPrice > 30000
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```